# Rrewrite two query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite this in .htaccess
So I have a query string in my url:

mysite.com/category/index.php?name=computers&pg=1

to like this
mysite.com/category/computers/1

I tried many times but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have tried but having no solution please try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?name=$1&pg=$2 [NC,L]
```

Put this .htaccess in category directory